# Getting undefined from passing function

Tags: javascript

I am practicing my javascript and copied the base logic from a book. This is the result:

```
function add(x,y, z) {
var anss = x+y+z;
return anss;
}
function subtract(x, y) {
    var ans = y - x;
    return ans;
}
function operations(func, value, value_1){
    func(value, value_1);
}
operations(subtract, 10, 5);
```

It returns undefined. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the function in `operations`:

```
function operations(func, value, value_1){
    return func(value, value_1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the book has a typo--not the best thing to learn from sometimes.